# Can GetSetting() be called in a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, windows-services, registry

I have written a window service.  and I am able to successfully install/run the service.  Now I have added a timer to the service and I want to be able to adjust the interval via the registry.  But I can't figure out why `GetSetting("MyAppName", "MySection", "IntervalSetting")` will NOT return the value in the registry!

Am I missing something?  Does GetSetting() not work when called from a windows service?

Comment: The service is running under the administrator account, and I am logged in as myself (i.e. NOT the administrator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN :

"GetSetting requires that a user be logged on since it operates under the HKEY_LOCAL_USER registry key, which is not active until a user logs on interactively."

What account does your service operate under? If it's LocalSystem, you effectively have no user logged on. Even if you impersonate, IIRC, that doesn't load the registry hive.

Answer (score 0):

does the user the service is running under have access to the registry?